# React-query into resuable hook with axios return error 400

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, react-query

Trying to use `react-query` with `axios` to make a reusable hook for state-management.

```
import { useMutation } from "react-query";

import axios from "axios";

const API_URL: string = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL!;

console.log(API_URL);

export const useLoginMutation = () =>
  useMutation((user: { email: string; password: string }) => {
    return axios.post(
      `${API_URL}/api/v1/users/login`,
      { user },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );
  });

// Component.tsx

mutateUser.mutate({ email: data.email, password: data.password });
```

Error:

[image]

But the login details are correct. it is asif the variables does not hit the API

Comment: Need more information. Please show the body of the request, to make sure that the credentials in request are correct. If so, check what's happening on the server (If you can).

Comment: Please check the function useLoginMutation

Comment: can you show the payload rather than the server response?

Comment: The payload is the user object that has email and password...